# Viewbag is not binding the value on post back to the controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using two viewbags to get the same list(List of tags) on get request these viewbags are showing list as a dropdown but when I submit the page (post request) they are binding the 0 values(no matter what I select from the dropdown list) with the object in the controller but when I used only the single dropdown list it binding its value with an object in the controller?

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult CreateNewTotalizerTag()
{
    //This is RawTag List
    var RawTaglist1 = cRTu.RawTagsList();
    ViewBag.RawTaglist1 = new SelectList(RawTaglist1, "Real_Tag_Id", "R_Tag_Name");

    //This is RawTag List
    var RawTaglist2 = cRTu.RawTagsList();
    ViewBag.RawTaglist2 = new SelectList(RawTaglist2, "Real_Tag_Id", "R_Tag_Name");

    return View();
}

//Controller
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateNewTotalizerTag(RawTagVM rawTagVM)
{

    return View(rawTagVM);
}





@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateNewTotalizerTag", "TotalizerTags", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.Real_Tag_Id)
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <!-- general form elements disabled -->
                <div class="card card-warning">
                    <div class="card-header" style="background-color:#343a40">
                        <h3 class="card-title" style="color:white">Create Totalizer Tag</h3>
                    </div>
                    <!-- This form is to create Raw tag totalizer onPrem or onCloud -->
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form role="form">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="custom-control custom-switch">

                                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Is_Cloud_Totalizer, new { @class = "custom-control-input", id = "Is_Cloud_Totalizer" })
                                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="Is_Cloud_Totalizer">Is Cloud Totalizer?</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- On Cloud Inputs starts here -->
                            <div  id="oncloud_totalizer" style="display:none">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Enter Tag Name</label>
                                            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.R_Tag_Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                            @*@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.R_Tag_Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })*@
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Select Raw Tag</label>
                                            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Real_Tag_Id_Cloud, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.RawTaglist1, "Select Raw Tag", new { @class = "form-control", id = "Raw_Tag_List1" })

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- On Prem Inputs starts here -->

                            <div class="row" id="onPrem_totalizer">
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Select Raw Tag</label>
                                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Real_Tag_Id, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.RawTaglist2, "Select Raw Tag", new { @class = "form-control", id = "Raw_Tag_List2" })

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <center><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create Totalizer</button></center>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.card-body -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.card -->
                <!-- general form elements disabled -->
                <!-- /.card -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        // Initialize select2
        //$("#Raw_Tag_List1").select2();
        //$("#Raw_Tag_List2").select2();



        //$("#Source_Tag_List").select2();

        $("#Is_Cloud_Totalizer").change(function () {
            if (this.checked) {
                $("#oncloud_totalizer").show();
                $("#onPrem_totalizer").hide();
            }
            else {
                $("#onPrem_totalizer").show();
               $("#oncloud_totalizer").hide();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please include the *full* view code.

Comment: @jerdine please check it now

Answer (score 0):

You could assign the viewbag properties on postback aswell. Viewbag properies are used in the view (cshtml) for rendering the page, the resulting rendered HTML page that is sent to the client does not know them, and also they are not sent back to the server together with form data on post back.

```
//Controller
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateNewTotalizerTag(RawTagVM rawTagVM)
{
    var RawTaglist1 = cRTu.RawTagsList();
    ViewBag.RawTaglist1 = new SelectList(RawTaglist1, "Real_Tag_Id", "R_Tag_Name");

    //This is RawTag List
    var RawTaglist2 = cRTu.RawTagsList();
    ViewBag.RawTaglist2 = new SelectList(RawTaglist2, "Real_Tag_Id", "R_Tag_Name");

    return View(rawTagVM);
}
```

You might try to assign the drop down a list of `SelectListItem`

```
ViewBag.RawTaglist1 = RawTaglist1.Select(x => new SelectListItem() 
{  
    Value = x.Real_Tag_Id.ToString(), 
    Text = x.R_Tag_Name
}).ToList();
```

Comment: i am assigning the actually I didn't post my complete controller here. The thing is that when I check the value in rawTagVM it has 0 against Real_Tag_Id and Real_Tag_Id_Cloud.;